# Github Actions with Terraform Cloud

Tags: terraform, github-actions, terraform-provider-aws

I have integrated Github Actions with Terraform Cloud and everything was running fine until yesterday. When I commit to the repo the workflow is run, but cannot finish:

```
Waiting for 3 run(s) to finish before being queued... (1h24m30s elapsed)
Waiting for 3 run(s) to finish before being queued... (1h25m0s elapsed)
Waiting for 3 run(s) to finish before being queued... (1h25m30s elapsed)
```

This is example to show you that I've waited long enough. Everytime I run the workflow, "runs" number ascends. What could cause this?

**Link to repo:** https://github.com/nnikolow/learn-terraform-github-actions

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just made it work - went to

**your-org/Workspaces/your-project/Runs/your-run**

through **RunID** in **Actions** tab in the repo and "released" the stuck run. I don't know why it got stuck, but now it works.